# Nexus camera intent controls crashing issue

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

I would like to build a simple camera intent to take a short video, however on the Nexus 6p after the user records the video they are presented with 3 controls, the large blue centre control works as intended by dismissing the camera, however the two smaller controls to the left and right crash the camera and don't give any debug messages to help figure out a possible fix, is there a way to hide or disable these controls as they are not needed for my specifications? I have attached two screenshots below illustrating the issue, any help would go a long way thanks.

[image]

[image]